# php can not connect to mysql after reboot server

Tags: php, mysql

Software:

- PHP 7.3
- MySQL Workbench 8.0

This is my PHP code:

```
try {
    $link = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME,3306);
} catch (Exception $e){
    throw new Exception("Can't execute command. ERROR: ".$e);
}
```

This is the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted in login.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'XXXXX_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ on line 11
>
> PHP Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ on line 24
>
> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: ERROR: Failed to connect to in C:\inetpub\wwwroot:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ on line 24

Now the magic, when I login in to mysql workbench with the same user and password everything works fine. I have access to tables and other things. When I login in with my PHP application everything works also.

So my problem is everytime my server reboots I have to login in with MySQL Workbench, to get it working again. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe problem is php openssl extension was not activated. You should check for php extension php_openssl.

Comment: Sorry for asking but... I presume you've double checked that it's logging in from Workbench what makes it all start working, and not just the coincidence that while you wait for Workbench to start you give MySQL Server time enough to do the same.

Comment: in my php.ini openssl is enabled. I can se this also in my phpinfo..
extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: the strange thing is that after i loggedin once into the workbench verything works fine even when i logged out from the workbench. everything keeps working. When i reboot the server where mysql is running on i have to loggin again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do verify few of the steps:

- All necessary extensions are enabled like `mysqli`, `openssl` etc
- Port is available
- `MySQLi` is connecting at 3306 Port
- Rest could be your `username` and `password` issue

Let us know once you will be verifying all above steps.

Comment: checked openssl this is okay. port , user and password are also okay because after i login once with workbench everything works great so the user,password and port must be okay. (by the way i've made a wrong password to check the connection and this failed so i'm using the right one)

Comment: OK right. In your code, can you try after removing port as by default its connecting with same 3306. Secondly, can you connect form command line with same credentials ? or you may check if user permissions from phpmyadmin.

Comment: I can login to mysql at the commandline. when after this i go to my php application this works also. when i exit the commandline everything still keeps working. It's like my php application is using the same instance and that php can't start the instance and when it's running iit's fine. When i look in workbench with the user root i don't see my session connected...i don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is enable the openssl extension for php.

Open your `php.ini` file and search for the line:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

You need to uncomment it by removing the semicolon in front of it, leaving you with this:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: it's uncommented. i can see that it's enabled in my phpinfo also